# dplyr identifying the middle sample within a group?

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi suppose I have the following dataframe.

```
df = read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/1meyd5snt6xo9le/plot.csv?dl=1")
df = df [ order ( df$group, df$total), ]

df$pid = factor ( df$pid, levels= df$pid )

> df
   pid total group
13 A13     1   Amy
14 A14     1   Amy
15 A15     1   Amy
16 A16     2   Amy
17 A17     2   Amy
18 A18     2   Amy
19 A19     2   Amy
20 A20     2   Amy
21 A21     7   Amy
22 A22     0 Cindy
23 A23     0 Cindy
24 A24     0 Cindy
25 A25     0 Cindy
26 A26     0 Cindy
27 A27     0 Cindy
28 A28     1 Cindy
29 A29     2 Cindy
30 A30     2 Cindy
31 A31     2 Cindy
32 A32     2 Cindy
33 A33     5 Cindy
34 A34     9 Cindy
35 A35     0  Etsy
36 A36     1  Etsy
37 A37     1  Etsy
38 A38     2  Etsy
39 A39     2  Etsy
40 A40     2  Etsy
41 A41     3  Etsy
42 A42     3  Etsy
43 A43     3  Etsy
44 A44     3  Etsy
1   A1     0  John
2   A2     0  John
3   A3     0  John
4   A4     1  John
5   A5     2  John
6   A6     3  John
7   A7     3  John
8   A8     4  John
9   A9     4  John
10 A10     7  John
11 A11    10  John
12 A12    14  John
```

What I want is to identify the middle pid for each group.  So for example for Cindy it would be around A28 since there are 13 rows and the ceiling ( 13/2) is 7.  I tried using dplyr with n() but that resets the rows.

This fails because it does not reset the row numbers

```
df %>% group_by( group )  %>%
  dplyr::summarise  (
    median = median ( total),
    mid.pid = df[ceiling ( n()/2 ), ]$pid
  )
```

Comment: Why do you use `df[...]$pid` it extracts the full column. instead you want `pid[ceiling(n()/2)]`

Comment: @akrun ah yes that works! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subsetting the original dataset based on the `ceiling` index will break the grouping.  We need to just use `pid` without any `$` or `[` as these `pid` are the elements of 'pid' within each group

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(group)  %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    median = median(total),
    mid.pid = pid[ceiling(n()/2)], .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  group median mid.pid
#* <chr>  <dbl> <fct>  
#1 Amy        2 A17    
#2 Cindy      1 A28    
#3 Etsy       2 A39    
#4 John       3 A6
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
data.frame('name' = unique(df[,'group']), 'pid' = 'NA') -> output
for(name in unique(df[,'group'])){
  df[ceiling(nrow(df[df[,'group'] == name, ])/2)), 'pid'] -> output[name, 'pid']
}
```

Which would create a dataframe containing the name and the pid value that is the ceiling of half of the number of times that name is in the dataframe.